# Is this approximation for a factorial a known formula?

Tags: exponentiation, approximation, factorial

I saw this approximation in some notes:

$n! \approx   e^{-n}*n^n*\sqrt{2\pi n}$

What is this approximation? How is it derived? Is it a known formula?

Comment: See [Stirling's formula.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

Comment: See [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

Comment: Note that:$$\ln(n!)=\sum_{k=2}^n\ln(k)$$and then apply the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula)